# RegEx for Google Analytics: matching URLs based on an appended separated id value within a string

Tags: regex, google-analytics

For a Google Analytics funnel I want to write a regEx that will match the URLs with the following pti ids:

1, 5, 8, 13, 14, 49, 79

For example, these are valid URLs

- /OrderProcess/OrderConfirmation.aspx?pti=1
- /OrderProcess/OrderConfirmation.aspx?pti=1|16
- /OrderProcess/OrderConfirmation.aspx?pti=48|1|47
- /OrderProcess/OrderConfirmation.aspx?pti=5|7|11

but these are not:

- /OrderProcess/OrderConfirmation.aspx?pti=16
- /OrderProcess/OrderConfirmation.aspx?pti=2|16|51

This regex matches URLs that start with the number but don't match numbers after the pipes:

```
.*OrderConfirmation.*pti=(1|5|8|13|14|49|79).*
```

There are nearly 100 ids and they could appear in the variable in any order. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the "word boundary" regex `\b`:

```
.*OrderConfirmation.*pti=.*\b(1|5|8|13|14|49|79)\b.*
```

Using the word boundary means id 1 doesn't match |17|.

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/al30jVYeMQ) on rubular of various edge cases.

Comment: thanks, this is good but it doesn't match urls like: /OrderProcess/OrderConfirmation.aspx?pti=22|5|7|11 where the id 5 is not first. this needs to match for all ids appearing in any  order.

Comment: @user2616169 I have added a link to an on-line demo showing this regex matching, and not matching, correctly. As the demo shows, in fact it *does* match where the id 5 is not first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the pipes, since they are reserved symbols in Regular Expressions:

```
.*OrderConfirmation.*pti=(1|1\|16)
```

Will match `/OrderProcess/OrderConfirmation.aspx?pti=1` and `/OrderProcess/OrderConfirmation.aspx?pti=1|16`.

(Adding the rest should be easy from here on.)

Note that if you write this:

```
.*OrderConfirmation.*pti=(1|1\|16).*
```

Then the expression will match `.*OrderConfirmation.*pti=1` or .*OrderConfirmation.*pti=1|16` *followed by anything*. If you want to allow other parameters (that aren't always there), you need this:

```
.*OrderConfirmation.*pti=(1|1\|16)($|&.*)
```

Which means that the first expression can either be followed by the end of string or `&` which can in turn be followed by anything.

Comment: Thanks mzedeler, I forgot to mention that there are nearly 100 ids and they could appear in the variable in any order. This would mean there are potentially loads of combinations and, as i understand, escaping the pipes I would need to write loads of potential combinations.

Comment: In that case, you have a completely different problem at your hands. I'll update my answer accordingly.